# Will the tail '-c' parameter only return the specified number of bytes of the line? Or will it return the entire line in chunks of -c bytes?

Tags: python, unix, logging, tail

I have a log file recieveing msgs of up to 8k bytes. I would like those messages to be smaller. I am currently tailing the log file with `tail -c +1 -F` however this grabs the entire 8k message which is to big. I would like to do something like `tail -c 2048 -F` however I don't want to lose and text from the msgs. Will `tail -c 1024 -F` cause me to lose some of the msg if the msg is over 1024 bytes?

Additional Info:
I am calling the tail command from python with and my regex filtering lags if the message is too large.

```
for line in sh.tail("-c", "4096", "-F", path, _iter=True):
    # Doing some regex filtering here
```

Comment: What object has a `tail` method?

Comment: From what *we can see in you code*, you're not "calling the tail command from python", you're passing some parameters to some `tail` method of a `sh` object.

Comment: `sh` is a package that allows one to call some system programs. Here are the docs:  http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#

Answer (score -1):

`tail -n +2` prints everything from second line to the end.
What you are looking for is rather `tail -n 2` or shorter: `tail -2` which will take the last two lines.

The same schema applies to bytes:

As `man tail` says:

`-c, --bytes=K
              output the last K bytes; alternatively, use -c +K to output bytes starting with the Kth of each file`

RTFM?

Comment: my docs on my unix system are not the same as yours, and appear to not be as descriptive.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#tail-invocation && http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail And next time please specify what unix flavour you are using, there are subtle differences between, for example, gnu/linux and solaris